# How to set BottonDownFcn to return the items place in the ordering like gname

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a function like `gname` to assign it to a point's callback
and when someone click on that point I could be able to retrieve its place
in the ordering of data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very hard time but used the UserData field to send the information in a for loop and
assign the value to each point as property and then simply getting it through dynamic callback.